# Error when add document in cloud Firestore : Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'User'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an error message when I add document in collection Activity in cloud firestore.

But after I add a other document in collection discussiongroups, this action work

```
myFunction() async{

inscris.add(widget.user);
_auteur=widget.user.ref;
Timestamp _dateCreate = Timestamp.now();

Map mapActivity= new Map<String, dynamic>();
mapActivity["description"]= _description;
mapActivity["titre"]= _titre;
mapActivity["inscris"]= inscris;
mapActivity["dateCreate"]= _dateCreate;
mapActivity["auteur"]= widget.user.ref;
mapActivity["town"]= _adresse;
mapActivity["nbPlaceMax"]= 12;
mapActivity["categorie"]= "sport";

List<DocumentReference> memberRef= new List<DocumentReference>();
memberRef.add(_auteur);

Map mapDiscussionGroup=new Map<String, dynamic>();
mapDiscussionGroup["active"]=true;
mapDiscussionGroup["membersRef"]=memberRef;
mapDiscussionGroup["titre"]= _titre;

callAddActivityFireHelper(mapActivity);
await Fire_helper().addGroupDiscussion(uidDiscussionGroups,mapDiscussionGroup);}



void callAddActivityFireHelper(Map mapActivity) async {
await Fire_helper().addActivity(mapActivity);
}
addActivity(Map<String, dynamic> map) async {

await fire_Activity.document().setData(map);
}
```

error message : [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'User'

Comment: It looks like you're trying to add a `User` object to Firestore, which is not a valid data type. For a list of valid data types, have a look at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @FrankvanPuffelen pointed out:

> "you are trying to add a `User` object to Firestore which is not a valid data type".

In order to use it you have to serialize it first.

[This doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) explains the whole process.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks. The error is not clear enough, now I get it.